# How to schedule Phone call event?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to schedule a phone call on an android application.

I currently have an onClick event for a button to make a phone call, I also have time and date picker and would like to be able to use them to schedule a time to make the call.

Any help would be appreciated.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter MSISDN Below" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/msisdn" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" android:inputType="phone">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="344dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter Schedule Time Below" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Set Call" android:onClick="makeCall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

************ *Class* *****************************************

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class CallAppActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void makeCall(View view) {
          Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry I figured it out. In case anyone is interested, I used a Handler to delay the intent action call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Intent myIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    String place = intent.getExtras().getString("place");
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+place));
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30727657)